# Perl Search and replace keeping middle part of string

Tags: perl

I've been using Codeigniter for my PHP project and I've been using their session class.

```
$this->session->userdata('variablename')
```

I've been having a lot of problems with this so i've decided to use PHP Native session.

```
$_SESSION['variablename']
```

This is what I've got so far

```
perl -p -i -e "s/$this->session->userdata('.*?$SOMEVAR.*?\')/$_SESSION['$1']/g" offer.php
```

But truth to be told I don't really know what I'm doing.

I would also like to do this on all php files in my project.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: first `$` is a specail regex char for end of line... when you want to match an actual `$` char you need to escape it `\$`... likewise for `(` or `)`chars
`s|\$this->session->userdata\((.*)\)|$_SESSION['$1']|g`

Comment: Do you have escaped single quotes inside the quoted field?

Answer (score 0):

The regex should be:

`s/\$this->session->userdata\('(.?)'\)/$_SESSION['$1']/g`

Issues with the version you posted are mostly with un-escaped characters--you can escape a `$` or parenthesis by adding a `\` prior to the character.  For example, `\$this` will find the text "$this", while `$this` will search for the value of the `$this` variable.

For a more comprehensive look at escapes (and other quick tips), if you have $2, I highly recommend [this cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/).

Also, you don't need to use the `.*?$SOMEVAR.*?` construct you added in there...Perl will automatically capture the result found between the first pair of parentheses and store it in `$1`, the second set of parentheses gets `$2`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When shell quoting is getting complicated, the simplest thing to do is to just put the source into a file. You can still use it as a one-liner. I have used a negative lookahead assertion to make sure that it does not break for escaped single quotes inside the string.

```
# source file, regex.txt
s/\$this->session->userdata\('(.+?)(?!\\')'\)/\$_SESSION['$1']/g;
```

**Usage:**

```
perl -pi regex.txt yourfile.php
```

Note that you simply leave out the `-e` switch. Also note that `-i` requires a backup extension for Windows, e.g. `-i.bak`.